# i would like to php 5.4 json support all language but its return Unicode and other unknown char

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, phpmyadmin

i would like to  php5.4 json support all language but its return Unicode and other unknown char. i have godaddy hosting, json View the original file in the following encoding: utf-8 encoding.  but its support always english language and i need to its support all other language like chinese, hindi etc.
i try for hindi language...
php code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli ( '50.xx.xx.xx:xx06', 'local', 'rootxxx', 'android');
$myq = $mysqli ->query ( 'SELECT id, url, name FROM onebabyapp' );
while ( $myr = $myq->fetch_assoc () ) {
   $array["items"][] = (array(
  'id' => $myr['id'],
  'url' => $myr['url'],
  'title' => $myr['name'],
 ));
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

but output like "title":"**\u0074\u0068\u0069\u0073\u005F\u0033**" 
but i expect "title":"समाचार" in hindi language  :(

second try......

```
  <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli ( '50.xx.xxx.xx:xxx6', 'local', 'rootxxx', 'android');
  if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
  printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   } else {
   // Check if album id is posted as GET parameter
  $myq = $mysqli ->query ( 'SELECT id, url, name FROM onebabyapp' );                          
  while ( $myr = $myq->fetch_assoc () ) {
  $array["items"][] = (array(
  'id' => $myr['id'],
  'id' => $myr['url'],
  'title' => $myr['name'],
   ));
   }
   }
  function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {
  return preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V',           hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($struct));
   }
  echo jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($array);
  ?>
```

but output like "title":"**à¤¸à¤®à¤¾à¤šà¤¾à¤°**"   :(
i need support Chinese, hindi, korian etc...

in **phpMyAdmin** table field i set Collation utf8_unicode_ci for all.
please help me.

Comment: The first output is in fact correct json encoding. What did you expect ?

Comment: i expect "title":"समाचार" in hindi language

Comment: As said in the link over, you could use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in the second parameter of `json_encode` but you might not want to do this. Think of how you would like to use your json (mainly javascript)

Comment: See this demo, proving that the encoding is good : http://jsfiddle.net/3xytrx2m/

Comment: thank you its working, i use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE and header(content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 )